# Grails publish-plugin not setting latest version

Tags: maven, grails, artifactory

We're getting a maven-metadata.xml file that looks like the following in Artifactory. The problem is that the release element has an old version.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <metadata>
      <groupId>com.commercehub</groupId>
      <artifactId>flight-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
      <versioning>
        <latest>1.0.8</latest>
        <release>1.0.8</release>
        <versions>
          <version>0.0.1</version>
          <version>1.0.1</version>
          <version>1.0.2</version>
          <version>1.0.3</version>
          <version>1.0.4</version>
          <version>1.0.5</version>
          <version>1.0.6</version>
          <version>1.0.7</version>
          <version>1.0.8</version>
          <version>1.0.9</version>
          <version>1.0.10</version>
        </versions>
        <lastUpdated>20150119115908</lastUpdated>
      </versioning>
    </metadata>
```

Manually deleting the xml file works but doesn't fix the root problem. Another plugin in the Artifactory repo doesn't run into this problem.

The command we use to publish:

```
grails publish-plugin --allow-overwrite --stack-trace
```

Comment: Which version of Artifactory are you using?

Comment: Artifactory Pro Power Pack 3.4.0

Comment: Can you deploy the plugin with "org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataCalculator" logging level set to trace

Comment: Do you get the maven-metadata.xml from a local repository or a virtual one?

Comment: Didn't get notified on your responses for some reason. This is a remote repository. I assume you mean the Bamboo Artifactory plugin.

Comment: I ment the type of repository in Artifactory, could be: local, remote or virtual. The type effects the way Artifactory calculates the maven-metadata.xml

Comment: Info from the person who supports the system "From my understanding of the context, you are using a local repo which means that the artifact itself lives primarily in the artifactory repo.  A remote artifact would be pulled from some external source like com.ibm.websphere… and then cached in artifactory for speedy access.  A virtual repo would be something like libs-release which doesn’t really exist as a repo but is series of places to look starting with libs-release-local and later includes ext-release-local."